# GCP cloud function UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, runtime-error

when running my cloud function i am using the test tool and supplying a valid json format i am getting this error line in the logs.

`Failed to publish message: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials should use fail() instead of throwing exceptions`

I am pretty new to GCP and i am not sure why it is doing this it almost seems to me that its not getting the service account details

this is my current code running in the cloud function.

```
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectTopicName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerBuilder;
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Map;

public class PublisherApi implements HttpFunction {// interface handles Http requests and responses

    private final Publisher publisher;
    private final Gson gson;

    public PublisherApi() throws IOException { // constructor used to get environment variables for instance of publisher
        String projectId = "projectName"; //System.getenv("GCP_PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID");
        String topicId = "topicIdArchive"; //System.getenv("GCP_PUBSUB_TOPIC_ID");

        ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
        System.out.println(topicName);// testing
        publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
        gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println("Constructed");

    }

    @Override
    public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws Exception { // entry point that handles http requests
        System.out.println("Starting the service");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()))) {
            int lineNum = 1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                System.out.println("Line " + lineNum++ + ":" + line);
            }

            String payload = sb.toString();
            Map<String, Object> payloadMap = gson.fromJson(payload, Map.class); //reads String object

            String jsonPayload = gson.toJson(payloadMap); //converts read object into Json object
            ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(jsonPayload);
            PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();

            ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
            ApiFutures.addCallback(future, new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to publish message: " + t.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
                    System.out.println("Message published successfully. Message ID: " + messageId);

                }
            });

            response.setStatusCode(200);
            response.getWriter().write("Message publish request sent");

        }   catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatusCode(500);
            response.getWriter().write("Failed to publish message");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            PublisherApi publisherApi = new PublisherApi();
            publisherApi.startServer();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startServer() throws IOException {
        ServerServiceDefinition serviceDefinition = ServerServiceDefinition.builder(PublisherApi.class.getName())
                .build();
        Server server = ServerBuilder
                .forPort(8080)
                .addService(serviceDefinition)
                .build();
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started on port 8080");

        try {
            server.awaitTermination();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

when running the test it should take in a json object like this

```
{
"tableId":"yourTableName",
"action":"INSERT",
"row":{
   "col1":"val1",
   "col2":"val2"
   ...
  }
}
```

this is basically getting a row from a cassandra table and sending it to a pubsub message to be extracted later and sent back to bigquery as a insert statement.

when this test message was submitted my logs looked good until i hit the prevoiusly stated error message.

Failed to publish message: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials should use fail() instead of throwing exceptions

I made sure the service account has the right roles for publishing.
I also tried using admin role in the service account to make sure i didnt miss any roles needed and still nothing changed.